# How to change default $PATH for root user in WSL2 (Ubuntu version)

Tags: bash, login, root, configuration

In the Ubuntu version running in WSL2 (on Windows 11), how do you change the default $PATH for the root user? I've tried adding the following lines to the root user's ".profile" script:

```
if [ -d "/mnt/c/Users/<my user>/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin" ] ; then
PATH="/mnt/c/Users/<my user>/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

And, this works if I login as root directly, but if I login as my regular user, then "su" to root, the default PATH isn't changed. So I'm guessing the .profile script isn't executed when you "su" to root, only when directly logging in as root.

How do I configure Ubuntu to change the default PATH in both cases?

Thanks!!

Comment: Use `su -` , `su -l`, or `su --login` if you want the shell to read root's `.profile`. Otherwise, place the changes in root's `.bashrc` instead.

Comment: I have no knowledge about WSL.  On my debian I created `/etc/default/su` file with content `ALWAYS_SET_PATH yes`